# How do I create vertical rectangles that are adjacent to each other with spaces in between?

Tags: shapes

I am working on a probability homework assignment for my discrete math class. One of the questions involves calculating the probability of drawing 7 cards and having exactly one land card and 6 non-land cards. We are given that we start off with 60 cards, 24 of which are land, and 36 of which are non-land.

I would like to use visuals (vertical rectangles that look like cards) to represent the various possible arrangements for this event.

In other words, I would like to draw a vertical rectangle with the letter "L" in it, and six other vertical rectangles with the letter "X" in each, with spaces in between each vertical rectangle.

How would I be able to do this?
Thanks so much for reading this.
Appreciate any help you can provide to me :D

Answer (score 2):

I could not imagine a problem of cards with boxed characters. I would need something more realistic:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker}
\psset{back=simple,backcolor=green}
\begin{document}
\crdflop\crdsevd\crdsixh\crdsixs 
\crdflop\crdfiveh\crdback\crdback\par 
\crdKd \crdback \crdback \crdpair{\crdKs}{\crdtenh} \crdpair{\crdQs}{\crdback} 
\end{document}
```

Warning: It takes time compile this `:(`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\framebox(12,20){L}
\framebox(12,20){X}
\framebox(12,20){}
\framebox(12,20){X}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! This is really helpful. How do I increase the spacing between the vertical rectangles? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Richard I just used a word space, but you could use `\hspace{3cm}` to have 3cm or whatever